# How to identify the records that belong to a certain time interval when I know the start and end records of that interval? (R)

Tags: r, intervals

So, here is my problem. I have a dataset of locations of radiotagged hummingbirds I’ve been following as part of my thesis. As you might imagine, they fly fast so there were intervals when I lost track of where they were until I eventually found them again.
Now I am trying to identify the segments where the bird was followed continuously (i.e., the intervals between “Lost” periods).

```
    ID  Type        TimeStart   TimeEnd     Limiter Starter Ender
    1   Observed    6:45:00     6:45:00     NO      Start   End 
    2   Lost        6:45:00     5:31:00     YES     NO      NO  
    3   Observed    5:31:00     5:31:00     NO      Start   NO  
    4   Observed    9:48:00     9:48:00     NO      NO      NO  
    5   Observed    10:02:00    10:02:00    NO      NO      NO  
    6   Observed    10:18:00    10:18:00    NO      NO      NO  
    7   Observed    11:00:00    11:00:00    NO      NO      NO  
    8   Observed    13:15:00    13:15:00    NO      NO      NO  
    9   Observed    13:34:00    13:34:00    NO      NO      NO  
    10  Observed    13:43:00    13:43:00    NO      NO      NO  
    11  Observed    13:52:00    13:52:00    NO      NO      NO  
    12  Observed    14:25:00    14:25:00    NO      NO      NO  
    13  Observed    14:46:00    14:46:00    NO      NO      End 
    14  Lost        14:46:00    10:47:00    YES     NO      NO  
    15  Observed    10:47:00    10:47:00    NO      Start   NO  
    16  Observed    10:57:00    11:00:00    NO      NO      NO  
    17  Observed    11:10:00    11:10:00    NO      NO      NO  
    18  Observed    11:19:00    11:27:55    NO      NO      NO  
    19  Observed    11:28:05    11:32:00    NO      NO      NO  
    20  Observed    11:45:00    12:09:00    NO      NO      NO  
    21  Observed    11:51:00    11:51:00    NO      NO      NO  
    22  Observed    12:11:00    12:11:00    NO      NO      NO  
    23  Observed    13:15:00    13:15:00    NO      NO      End 
    24  Lost        13:15:00    7:53:00     YES     NO      NO  
    25  Observed    7:53:00     7:53:00     NO      Start   NO  
    26  Observed    8:48:00     8:48:00     NO      NO      NO  
    27  Observed    9:25:00     9:25:00     NO      NO      NO  
    28  Observed    9:26:00     9:26:00     NO      NO      NO  
    29  Observed    9:32:00     9:33:25     NO      NO      NO  
    30  Observed    9:33:35     9:33:35     NO      NO      NO  
    31  Observed    9:42:00     9:42:00     NO      NO      NO  
    32  Observed    9:44:00     9:44:00     NO      NO      NO  
    33  Observed    9:48:00     9:48:00     NO      NO      NO  
    34  Observed    9:48:30     9:48:30     NO      NO      NO  
    35  Observed    9:51:00     9:51:00     NO      NO      NO  
    36  Observed    9:54:00         9:54:00     NO      NO      NO  
    37  Observed    9:55:00         9:55:00     NO      NO      NO  
    38  Observed    9:57:00     10:01:00    NO      NO      NO  
    39  Observed    10:02:00    10:02:00    NO      NO      NO  
    40  Observed    10:04:00    10:04:00    NO      NO      NO  
    41  Observed    10:06:00    10:06:00    NO      NO      NO  
    42  Observed    10:20:00    10:33:00    NO      NO      NO  
    43  Observed    10:34:00    10:34:00    NO      NO      NO  
    44  Observed    10:39:00    10:39:00    NO      NO      End
```

Note: When there is a “Start” and an “End” in the same row it’s because the non-lost period consists only of that record.

I was able to identify the records that start or end these “non-lost” periods (under the columns “Starter” and “Ender”), but now I want to be able to identify those periods by giving them unique identifiers (period A,B,C or 1,2,3, etc). 
Ideally, the name of the identifier would be the name of the start point for that period (i.e., ID[ Starter==”Start”])

I'm looking for something like this:

```
    ID  Type        TimeStart   TimeEnd     Limiter Starter Ender   Period

    1   Observed    6:45:00     6:45:00     NO      Start   End     1
    2   Lost        6:45:00     5:31:00     YES     NO      NO      Lost    
    3   Observed    5:31:00     5:31:00     NO      Start   NO      3
    4   Observed    9:48:00     9:48:00     NO      NO      NO      3
    5   Observed    10:02:00    10:02:00    NO      NO      NO      3
    6   Observed    10:18:00    10:18:00    NO      NO      NO      3
    7   Observed    11:00:00    11:00:00    NO      NO      NO      3
    8   Observed    13:15:00    13:15:00    NO      NO      NO      3
    9   Observed    13:34:00    13:34:00    NO      NO      NO      3
    10  Observed    13:43:00    13:43:00    NO      NO      NO      3
    11  Observed    13:52:00    13:52:00    NO      NO      NO      3
    12  Observed    14:25:00    14:25:00    NO      NO      NO      3
    13  Observed    14:46:00    14:46:00    NO      NO      End     3
    14  Lost        14:46:00    10:47:00    YES     NO      NO      Lost    
    15  Observed    10:47:00    10:47:00    NO      Start   NO      15
    16  Observed    10:57:00    11:00:00    NO      NO      NO      15
    17  Observed    11:10:00    11:10:00    NO      NO      NO      15
    18  Observed    11:19:00    11:27:55    NO      NO      NO      15
    19  Observed    11:28:05    11:32:00    NO      NO      NO      15
    20  Observed    11:45:00    12:09:00    NO      NO      NO      15
    21  Observed    11:51:00    11:51:00    NO      NO      NO      15
    22  Observed    12:11:00    12:11:00    NO      NO      NO      15
    23  Observed    13:15:00    13:15:00    NO      NO      End     15
    24  Lost        13:15:00    7:53:00     YES     NO      NO      Lost
```

Would this be too hard to do in R?

Thanks!

Comment: reproducible code would be nice

Comment: Can you post reproducible code with dates?  I would look to findInterval() with timestamps.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, I am new at this. What do you mean with "reproducible code"? The R code I used to get to this point? Or a data table you could download? (If the latter, that was my original idea but didn't know how to do it)

Comment: reproducible code allows one to copy, paste into script editor and run.  See answer below for example. you might need to simplify the data set to reduce size but still be representative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> d <- data.frame(Limiter = rep("NO", 44), Starter = rep("NO", 44), Ender = rep("NO", 44), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> d$Starter[c(1, 3, 15, 25)] <- "Start"
> d$Ender[c(1, 13, 23, 44)] <- "End"
> d$Limiter[c(2, 14, 24)] <- "Yes"
> d$Period <- ifelse(d$Limiter == "Yes", "Lost", which(d$Starter == "Start")[cumsum(d$Starter == "Start")])
> d
       Limiter Starter Ender Period
1       NO   Start   End      1
2      Yes      NO    NO   Lost
3       NO   Start    NO      3
4       NO      NO    NO      3
5       NO      NO    NO      3
6       NO      NO    NO      3
7       NO      NO    NO      3
8       NO      NO    NO      3
9       NO      NO    NO      3
10      NO      NO    NO      3
11      NO      NO    NO      3
12      NO      NO    NO      3
13      NO      NO   End      3
14     Yes      NO    NO   Lost
15      NO   Start    NO     15
16      NO      NO    NO     15
17      NO      NO    NO     15
18      NO      NO    NO     15
19      NO      NO    NO     15
20      NO      NO    NO     15
21      NO      NO    NO     15
22      NO      NO    NO     15
23      NO      NO   End     15
24     Yes      NO    NO   Lost
25      NO   Start    NO     25
26      NO      NO    NO     25
27      NO      NO    NO     25
28      NO      NO    NO     25
29      NO      NO    NO     25
30      NO      NO    NO     25
31      NO      NO    NO     25
32      NO      NO    NO     25
33      NO      NO    NO     25
34      NO      NO    NO     25
35      NO      NO    NO     25
36      NO      NO    NO     25
37      NO      NO    NO     25
38      NO      NO    NO     25
39      NO      NO    NO     25
40      NO      NO    NO     25
41      NO      NO    NO     25
42      NO      NO    NO     25
43      NO      NO    NO     25
44      NO      NO   End     25
```

Comment: You probably would want to avoid hard coding in the row indexes

Comment: I didn't notice that you want the ID to be when each period starts, but that's easy enough to change.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I was just trying to create the data the OP displayed. I was under the impression that the OP already had the first data set and was just trying to create the Period column

Comment: @JakeBurkhead Thanks!!! As you said, all I wanted was to create the Period column based on a table I already have. What you did there is awesome. But given you said that changing the values of period to when the ID period starts is easy, could you please show me how to do it? :)